# how to handle a media file without save it in django

Tags: python, django

In my django project, I received a media file posted from client. like this

```py
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], request.POST['fid'])
            return JsonResponse({"result":"ok"})
    return JsonResponse({"result":"failed","msg":"unkown"})


def handle_uploaded_file(f, fid):
    with open(STEP_DIR + '/' + fid, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

On the other hand, I want to process this file by another module. And this module will open a file and handle it like this:

```
Import thirdModule
thirdModule.open('path_to_url').exporter(...)
```

As the **thirdModule** will open a file by a given path. So I have to save the file which I had just received from django ?
Is there any way I can process the file directly with out save it.like is:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f, fid):
    thirdModule.open(convert_media_to_stream(f))
    ...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635524/django-open-uploaded-file-while-still-in-memory-in-the-form-clean-method

Answer (score 0):

```
if form.is_valid():
    data = form.cleaned_data
    inmemory_uploaded_file = data['file_field_name']
    file_name = str(inmemory_uploaded_file)
    process_file_without_saving_into_disk(inmemory_uploaded_file)
    # rest of your code
```

**Update**

```
def handle_upload(file, file_name, upload_path):
    if not os.path.exists(upload_path):
        os.mkdir(upload_path)

    file_path = os.path.join(upload_path, file_name)
    with open(file_path, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    return file_path
```

Comment: I got this error: **TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found**

Comment: `process_file_without_saving_into_disk` is your defined function to process the file. If your function receives two arguments, one takes the file and the other takes the file name, then pass those accordingly.

Comment: The problem is my function only receive one arguments

Comment: Then pass `inmemory_uploaded_file` to your function and treat the argument as if you've read the file and passed it to the function as argument.

Comment: the function is not defined by me. It from an another big project. And that function finally redirect to a c++ function. So, for me, it's a big work to change that api.

Comment: I got a idea. I can open a file in write mode with a specified name. And then, I write the InMemoryUploadedFile to that file with out close it. Then I can use that filename for my function !

Comment: ultimately you are saving the file to disk. If you want to do this then see **Update** part of my answer

Comment: I mean , If I can use one file and without close it totally. every time I receive a new media file, I can just flush that file, and write new data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195942/discussion-between--and-mahmood-al-rayhan).